# How to show grid for a custom x axis label: achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

I want a functionality where if user clicks on the the graph and if the x co ordinate is close to our point on XY line graph then I want to show a vertical grid for that point.

The only function that seems related is 
mRenderer.setShowCustomTextGridY(boolean showGrid)

But for which value should the grid be shown is not clear in the documentation.

Please help. Which function should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the X axis value, you can add a custom text label this way:

```
renderer.addXTextLabel(x, "label");
```

Then, if you call a `mChartView.repaint()`, the custom text grid will be displayed.

Comment: Thanks Dan, and how to set custom color of this custom grid?

Comment: renderer.setGridColor(color);

Comment: That isnt working, even the normal grid colors are not working. I am using the folloeing code

mRenderer.setGridColor(Color.BLUE);
  mRenderer.setShowGridX(true);
  mRenderer.setAxesColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.gray_light));

the axes color is getting changed but not for the grid.

Comment: @Dan can you help here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22965479/graph-goes-out-of-view-when-margin-color-set-to-transparent-in-achartengine

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
renderer.setShowCustomTextGrid(true);
```