# Graph goes out of view when margin color set to transparent in AchartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine

I am trying to match the line chart background with the whole layout bg. so i tried following to set the background of chart. It matched with the bg but when i dragged the graph it goes out of view.

```
mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00));
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

If needed further information, let me know.

Please help guys.

Here is the code

```
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

    XYSeries mSeries = new XYSeries("Weight");

    for (int i = 0; i < weight_list.size(); i++) {

        mSeries.add(i + 1, Double.parseDouble(weight_list.get(i)));
    }

    mDataset.addSeries(mSeries);

    XYSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    seriesRenderer.setPointStrokeWidth(25);
    seriesRenderer.setShowLegendItem(false);
    seriesRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
    seriesRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    seriesRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(30);
    seriesRenderer.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    seriesRenderer.setLineWidth(3);

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    // mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(25);
    mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(25);
    mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.WHITE);
    mRenderer.setXTitle("\nWeeks in Program");
    mRenderer.setGridColor(Color.WHITE);
    mRenderer.setYTitle("Weight (Lb)");
    mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
//  mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 0, 60, 0, 0 });
//  mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01));
    mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00));
    mRenderer.setPointSize(5);
    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, true);
    mRenderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { 0, 50, 0, 500 });
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(seriesRenderer);


   chartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, mDataset, mRenderer);
   graphLayout.addView(chartView);
```

Comment: Are u giving margins ?

Comment: @keshav i am setting margins, if i comment the margins then also it goes out of chart.

Comment: Plz show code, not possible without looking at code.

Comment: I suggest you don't use transparent margins. This is because margins are drawn above everything else, but if they are transparent...