# How to display Y-axis grid lines in bar graph using AChart engine

Tags: android, achartengine

The Y-Axis grid lines are not getting displayed in bar graph using A-Chart engine.Even after using `setShowGrid(true)` and using `setShowGridY(true)`,the Y-axis grid lines are not getting displayed in bar graph chart.
It will be of great help,if somebody provides a correct way of doing that.

Comment: can u show what are u doing?

Answer (score 3):

Use
`renderer.setShowCustomTextGrid(true);`

Courtesy @Beben06 [How to show grid for a custom x axis label: achartengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344743/how-to-show-grid-for-a-custom-x-axis-label-achartengine)?